# The 13,601st puzzle

Tags: riddle, story

*One day, a man was watching a live TV report. He was a good puzzler.*

TV Report.

This is just in, by Justin.
A child of an art collector noticed that every time she left the house, the paintings would be laid on the ground.

The art collector was at a museum, and she said "**oh no!**" because her house has gold somewhere only she knew. But it seemed like trouble.

The only other person there was Fran, who liked country music.

Fran would hang the paintings up again each time, but they kept neatly 'falling' down.

The police were suspicious, but he testified "I had nothing to do with it, it's actually rather annoying, and I don't even know where the gold is!".

Currently, the police are stumped, but they found the gold, which was someplace  confidential.

**The man immediately knew what was going on, and Fran was arrested 17 hours later.**

Why was he arrested? What's the real story?

Hint:

> The *painted* gold was hidden in plain sight, and hanging up paintings had to do with where it was hidden.

Another hint:

> Painted s _ _ e _ _ were where the gold was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the gold would be hidden...

> painted onto the **S**CR**E**WS that held the paintings up. Fran kept taking the paintings down so that he could replace the gold-covered screws with regular screws.

To be honest though, I felt like the hints may have been slightly unnecessary, although they did reinforce my guess.